# Generating a number inside of a loop

Tags: java

I have to create a program of a virtual rock, paper scissors game. I have got most of it figured out but am having an issue with getting a random number from 1-3 to generate every time the user enters their play. I will show both classes below, first the user and then the computer class. any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

User:

```
    public String play()
{

    do{

    switch (userChoice) {
        case R:
        {
            System.out.println("You have chosen rock.");

            if (robot.getComputerChoice().equals(paper)){
                System.out.println("You lose! \nPaper covers rock!");
                numOfLosses ++;
            }

            else if (robot.getComputerChoice().equals(scissors)){
                System.out.println("You win! \nRock smashes scissors!");
                numOfWins ++;
            }
            else if (robot.getComputerChoice().equals(rock)){
                    System.out.println("Its a tie!");
                    numOfTies ++;
            }
            userChoice = result;
        }
            break;
        case P:
        {
            System.out.println("You have chosen paper.");

            if (robot.getComputerChoice().equals(rock)){
                System.out.println("You win! \nPaper covers rock!");
                numOfWins ++;
            }
            else if (robot.getComputerChoice().equals(scissors)){
                System.out.println("You lose! \nScissors cuts paper!");
                numOfLosses ++;
            }
            else if (robot.getComputerChoice().equals(paper)){
                    System.out.println("Its a tie!");
                    numOfTies ++;
            }
            userChoice = result;

        }
            break;
        case S:
        {
            System.out.println("You have chosen scissors.");

            if (robot.getComputerChoice().equals(rock)){
                System.out.println("You lose! \nRock smashes scissors!");
                numOfLosses ++;
            }
            else if (robot.getComputerChoice().equals(paper)){
                System.out.println("You win! \nScissors cuts paper!");
                numOfWins ++;
            }
            else if (robot.getComputerChoice().equals(scissors)){
                    System.out.println("Its a tie!");
                    numOfTies ++;
            }
            userChoice = result;
        }
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("That input was invalid.");
            break;
    }

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Lets play Rock, Paper, Sciccors!");
        System.out.println("(R)ock, (P)aper, or (S)cissors? 0 to end the game.");

        userChoice = scan.next();    
        userChoice = userChoice.toUpperCase();

    } while (!userChoice.equals(EXIT));

    System.out.println("Thanks for playing!");
    System.out.println("Number of wins: " + numOfWins + "\nNumber of losses: "
            + numOfLosses + "\nNumber of ties: " + numOfTies);

    total = numOfWins + numOfLosses + numOfTies;

    winPercentage = (numOfWins/total) * 100;

    System.out.printf(userName + "'s win percentage: %.2f", winPercentage);
    System.out.print("%");

    return result;
```

Computer:

```
    public Computer() {

    Random rand = new Random();

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    COMPUTERNAME = "Bob";

    while (){ // can't figure out what to do here.

        generateNumber = rand.nextInt(3)+1; // 1 to 3

    switch (generateNumber) {
        case 1:
            computerChoice = "rock";
            break;
        case 2:
            computerChoice = "paper";
            break;
        case 3:
            computerChoice = "scissors";
            break;
        default:
            break; 
        } 
    } 
} 


public String getComputerChoice()
    {
        return computerChoice;
    }


public String getComputerName()
    {    
        System.out.print("My name is ");
        System.out.print(COMPUTERNAME);
        System.out.println(", your computer opponent.");

        return COMPUTERNAME;
    }
```

Comment: Java is to Javascript as Pain is to Painting, or Ham is to Hampster. They are completely different. It is highly recommended that aspiring coders try to learn the name of the language they're attempting to write code in. When you post a question, please tag it appropriately.

Comment: `while (true) { ... }` for a repeating loop?

Comment: Dave, I need it to produce a random int every time the user enters input.

Comment: A good idea could be to move the random number code into `Computer#getComputerChoice`. That way, you don't have to create a new `Computer` object whenever you want a new computer guess: just call the method. Following that logic, you don't need a loop in the `Computer` object since you are already looping in the `User` class.

Comment: Also note, the problem with where you are trying to loop right now is that it is the [constructor](https://www.dummies.com/programming/java/how-to-use-a-constructor-in-java/) of your `Computer` class. So if you loop there forever, the `Computer` object will never be created and in turn will never be able to be used by your `User` object.

Comment: okay, so it worked by generating a random number but now if I print the computer choice it will be different then what it should be ie: computer chose rock - user wins by choosing scissors?